# Using XSETBV to write to XCR0 creates a general protection fault in a VM on hardware that supports MPX

Tags: c, linux-kernel, x86, virtual-machine, vmware

I am trying to write to Extended Control Register 0 (`xcr0`) on an x86_64 Debian v7 virtual machine. My approach to doing so is through a kernel module (so `CPL=0`) with some inline assembly. However, I keep getting a general protection fault (`#GP`) when I try to execute the `xsetbv` instruction.

The `init` function of my module first checks that the `osxsave` bit is set in control register 4 (`cr4`). If it isn't, it sets it. Then, I read the `xcr0` register using `xgetbv`. This works fine and (in the limited testing I have done) has the value `0b111`. I would like to set the `bndreg` and `bndcsr` bits which are the 3rd and 4th bits (0-indexed), so I do some `OR`ing and write `0b11111` back to `xcr0` using `xsetbv`. The code to achieve this last part is as follows.

```
unsigned long xcr0;             /* extended register    */
unsigned long bndreg = 0x8;     /* 3rd bit in xcr0      */
unsigned long bndcsr = 0x10;    /* 4th bit in xcr0      */

/* ... checking cr4 for osxsave and reading xcr0 ... */

if (!(xcr0 & bndreg))
    xcr0 |= bndreg;

if (!(xcr0 & bndcsr))
    xcr0 |= bndcsr;

/* ... xcr0 is now 0b11111 ... */

/*
 * write changes to xcr0; ignore high bits (set them =0) b/c they are reserved
 */
unsigned long new_xcr0 = ((xcr0) & 0xffffffff);
__asm__ volatile (
    "mov $0, %%ecx      \t\n" // %ecx selects the xcr to write
    "xor %%rdx, %%rdx   \t\n" // set %rdx to zero
    "xsetbv             \t\n" // write from edx:eax into xcr0
    :
    : "a" (new_xcr0)        /* input    */
    : "ecx", "rdx"          /* clobbered    */
);
```

By looking at the trace from the general protection fault, I determined that the `xsetbv` instruction is the problem. However, if I don't manipulate `xcr0` and just read its value and write it back, things seem to work fine. Looking at the Intel manual and [this site](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/xsetbv), I found various reasons for a `#GP`, but none of them seem to match my situation. The reasons are as follows along with my explanation for why they most likely don't apply.

- If the current privilege level is not 0 --> I use a kernel module to achieve `CPL=0`
- If an invalid `xcr` is specified in `%ecx` --> 0 is in `%ecx` which is valid and worked for `xgetbv`
- If the value in `edx:eax` sets bits that are reserved in the `xcr` specified by `ecx` --> according to the Intel manual and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_register) the bits I am setting are not reserved
- If an attempt is made to clear bit 0 of `xcr0` --> I printed out `xcr0` before setting it, and it was `0b11111`
- If an attempt is made to set `xcr0[2:1]` to `0b10` --> I printed out `xcr0` before setting it, and it was `0b11111`

Thank you in advance for any help discovering why this `#GP` is happening.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you can shorten your asm block a lot, and probably generate more efficient code, like this: `__asm__ volatile ("xsetbv" : : "a" (new_xcr0), "c" (0), "d" (0));`.

Comment: When you say "I printed out `xcr0` before setting it", do you actually mean `new_xcr0`? And what value exactly did it have?

Comment: If you're going to zero 2 registers inside the inline asm statement, do them both the same way, with [`xor`-zeroing of the 32-bit register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and) (which implicitly zero-extends to 64-bit).  It's inconsistent to use 2 different ways of zeroing, and you picked both sub-optimal ways :/

Comment: Are you sure all the bits you are twiddling in xcr0 correspond to features that are implemented *on your specific processor*?

Comment: Are you trying to enable MPX inside your VM?  `xsetbv` might trap to the hypervisor, and the hypervisor might not have MPX support even if your VM does.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica yes I meant `new_xcr0` I printed it out and it was `0b11111` as I wanted.

Comment: @MichaelPetch the upper 32 bits (stored in `edx`) are all reserved and thus zero so I just make the entire register zero. Then I pass the low bits in `eax`...well technically `rax` but `xsetbv` just looks in `eax`.

Comment: @NateEldredge my processor supports MPX which is what I am trying to enable in the VM.

Comment: @PeterCordes can you elaborate please? How can I discover if my hypervisor has MPX support?

Comment: @peachykeen: hopefully CPUID inside the VM reflects that (bit cleared if not supported). 
 Check /proc/cpuinfo *inside the VM*.  But possibly a hypervisor might be buggy and pass on the MPX flag but fault if you try to use it.

Comment: I thought the deal with the reserved bits in edx is that you should keep them the same as what you read, not that you should clear them.  Maybe they are all zero anyway but just another thing to check.

Comment: @NateEldredge the reserved bits are all zero - I just checked.

Comment: @PeterCordes  `/proc/cpuinfo` on the VM doesn't list `mpx` in the flags (it does list `xsave` though). My host does have MPX support though. I am running Linux kernel version 3.19 which does support MPX and I already have a binary compiled with MPX (the `bnd` instructions etc. are all there when I `objdump`). The problem is that the instructions get treated as `NOP`s. I thought the process I described above would fix this and enable the CPU to recognize MPX.

Comment: So you're trying to change it from `0b111` to `0b11111`? Can you successfully change it to `0b1111` or `0b10111`?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I cannot do `0b10111` or `0b1111` - both give me a `#GP`.

Comment: Can you find any values you can change it to, other than just setting it back to what it already is?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica No, nothing else works.

Comment: @PeterCordes what is ```processor state components``` mean, after going throw the docs they keep mentioning it every time they are talking about the xcr0 register

Comment: @PeterCordes in another way, what are they saving in term of the context

Comment: @zerocool: I don't know, I haven't read those docs.  But looking at the docs for `xsetbv`, it mentions for example "the x87 state", "SSE state", and "AVX state".  So pretty obviously the same architectural state (i.e. register values) that `xsaveopt` and so on will save/restore.  The pseudocode in https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/xsaveopt#operation mentions more explicitly what each piece of state is (which registers).  Unfortunately https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architectural_state is currently very bad, claiming that pipeline buffers between stages are part of the *architectural* state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Peter Cordes was right, it was a problem with my hypervisor. I am using VMWare Fusion for virtualization, and after a lot of digging on the internet I found the following quote from VMWare:

> Memory protection extensions (MPX) were introduced in Intel Skylake generation CPUs and provided hardware support for bound checking. This feature will not be supported in Intel CPUs beginning with the Ice Lake generation.
>
> Starting with ESXi 6.7 P02 and ESXi 7.0 GA, in order to minimize disruptions during future upgrades, VMware will no longer expose MPX by default to VMs at power-on. A VM configuration option can be used to continue exposing MPX.

The solution VMWare proposed was to edit the virtual machine's `.vmx` file with the following directive.

```
cpuid.enableMPX = "TRUE"
```

After I did this, things worked and I was able to use `xsetbv` to enable the `bndreg` and `bndcsr` bits of `xcr0`.

---

When using VMWare to expose CPU features from the host to the guest under more normal conditions (i.e. the feature isn't plagued with deprecation) you can mask the bits of `cpuid` leaves by adding the following to the VM's `.vmx` file.

```
cpuid.<leaf>.<register> = "<value>"
```

So, for example, if we assume that SMAP can be exposed this way, we would want to set bit 20 of `cpuid` leaf 7.

```
cpuid.7.ebx = "----:----:---1:----:----:----:----:----"
```

Colons are optional to ease reading of the string, ones and zeros override any default settings, and dashes are used to leave default setting alone.

Answer (score 2):

> `/proc/cpuinfo` on the VM doesn't list mpx in the flags (it does list xsave though). My host does have MPX support though. I am running Linux kernel version 3.19 which does support MPX and I already have a binary compiled with MPX (the bnd instructions etc. are all there when I objdump). The problem is that the instructions get treated as NOPs. I thought the process I described above would fix this and enable the CPU to recognize MPX.

It would enable MPX if you ran it on a machine that supported MPX.  (Assuming your code is correct.)

The virtual x86 CPU your VM is running on does not, according to its own virtualized CPUID, so it's not surprising at all that this faults.  The hypervisor might be doing this manually in a VMEXIT, emulating `xsetbv` and checking the changes to the virtualized xcr0.

**If you want to use features your HW has but your VM doesn't support, in general you have to run on bare metal instead.  Or find a different VM that does expose the feature to the guest.**

Note that MPX introduces new architectural state (the `bnd` registers) that have to get saved/restored on context switches.  If your hypervisor doesn't want to do that, that would be one reason to disable MPX.  (I think it can get saved/restored as part of `xsave`, but it does make the save slightly larger.)  I haven't looked at MPX much; it might be something the hypervisor would have to deal with in vmexits to not have bounds checking apply to the hypervisor...  If so that would be a major inconvenience.

Comment: Thank you, as always, for your thoughtful answer @Peter Cordes. I found the specific solution to my problem and posted that, though your answer was helpful in getting there.